# Brakes seized up due to inactivity

Tags: brakes

I know brakes can seize up due to various reasons including inactivity.  Car was parked up for many months so I'm guessing it was due to inactivity.

How does inactivity cause brakes to seize, what will I need to do to repair, will I need to replace the effected caliper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All these issues will be due to moisture and rust.  If the semi-metallic pads are frozen to the rotors, this can be corrected with some brute force.

If water has contaminated the brake fluid, this can cause caliper pistons to seize in the calipers.  This may be to poor maintenance or torn dust boots on the caliper pistons.  If pads are worn down too far, the piston may spend too much time over-extended, allowing moisture to rust the piston outside of the o-ring seal.

*Sometimes* the affected piston can be pressed back into the caliper without damage.  This is an iffy prospect at best.  Most often it is cheaper to replace the caliper than attempt a rebuild yourself.

Obviously if the vehicle is maintained and operated regularly, there isn't enough time to build the kind of rust necessary to seize the brake components.